# Neo4j - count relationships vs store the no. of relationships

Tags: performance, neo4j, count, notifications, graph-databases

I'm feeling good to work with Neo4j as I'm building a social network and neo4j is working well for me. Please answer to these points:

1) I'm stuck at making a decision as to store the number of likes on a post (de-normalized)somewhere in the database or should I count the number of edges to that post dynamically every time.

For example, When retrieving the "post" json data, for each user who needs that data, I need to count the no. of edges everytime I generate json.

2) Stuck at deciding best way to notify users about likes or comments.
For example, I want to push a notification to the user saying "John and 3 others also commented on Cena's post". 
This notification might be updated as the number of comments increases. So, it's helpful for me to update notification if I'm using count(*) rather than than storing the counter somewhere, because I can fetch the count of "${count} new replies on your post" easily. But I'm worried about the performance.

3) Can I use Redis or other memcache with neo4j? Does that make a "significant" difference?
Please help me out in deciding which is better.

P.S: Please keep in mind the efficiency and scalability of application.

Comment: There's actually a great series on the subject on Max De Marzi's site. Check https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/03/30/building-a-twitter-clone-with-neo4j-part-one/ for the first episode (there's eight episodes in all). Most - if not all - of your questions are handled in the series.

Comment: Thanks @TomGeudens, That link made sense. So, as the docs say, getDegree is a constant time operation and doesn't effect performance.